# Powershell send mail message with attachment - delays sending until 30+ minutes

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure why this happens, when I send to only 1 recipient the attachment and email are received within about a minute, when I send to all recipients (8) it takes 30+ minutes to receive.. or just fails entirely.

```
  # Send the email

  $rec1 = "someone1@someone.com"
 $recipients = @(
"someone1@someone.com"
  "someone2@someone.comm"
   "someone3@someone.com"
    "someone4@someone.com"
     "someone5@someone.comm"
      "someone6@someone.com"
       "someone7@someone.com"
        "someone8@someone.com"
      )


# Set email parameters
$smtpServer = "myaddress"
$smtpFrom = $rec1
$smtpTo = $recipients
$messageSubject = "Subject Placeholder"
$messageBody = "Hi, forecast is attached."
# Get the latest file in the folder
$folderPath = "C:\Users\Forecast"
$latestFile = Get-ChildItem $folderPath | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
# Set attachment parameters
$attachmentPath = $latestFile.FullName
$attachmentName = $latestFile.Name
# Create and send the email
$mailmessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage
$mailmessage.from = ($smtpFrom)
$mailmessage.To.add($smtpTo)
$mailmessage.Subject = $attachmentName
$mailmessage.Body = $messageBody
# Attach the latest file
$attachment = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachmentPath)
$mailmessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
# Set email client
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
# Send email
$smtp.Send($mailmessage)
# Dispose of the attachment
$attachment.Dispose()
```

Comment: `$mailmessage.To.add($smtpTo)` is wrong, it should be `$smtpto | ForEach {  $mailmessage.To.add($_) }`

Answer (score 0):

The delay was me not specifying the port for my server..